# Cuda return custom types

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to make a vector library using CUDA. Most of my functions have the return type `Vector< N, T >`. I am very new to CUDA.

For example, I am overloading the `+` operator

```
template< unsigned int N, class T, class S >
__global__ inline Vector< N, T > operator +( const Vector< N, T >& lhs, const Vector< N, S >& rhs )
{
    Vector< N, T > result( lhs );
    return result += rhs;
}
```

That does not work because:

```
error: An operator function cannot be a __global__ function

error: a __global__ function must have a void return type
```

`__device__` does not work also

Overloading is just an example. I have a bunch of functions, their return types are `Vector< N, T >`

How can I execute them on GPU?

Comment: Programming with CUDA is quite different than "regular" code for the CPU. I suggest you start with some CUDA tutorials.

Comment: Just have the `operator` overloads being host wrappers which call the respective kernels. How would you specify the block- and grid-size for `a + b`? Also you wouldn't want these details to be part of the API either way. So for this kind of use case you don't want classes that live in GPU memory, but classes on the CPU that have pointers to GPU memory and offload their compute to the GPU.

Comment: Not sure of my comment above targets the exact use case that you have in mind. But for the per-thread case I don't see how you would learn much about CUDA by implementing it. Device functions are not that different from what one does on the host. You should have included the error message for `__device__`.

Answer (score 1):

as @wohlstad i would suggest to read some cuda tutorials or the [CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-declaration-specifiers).

the keyword `__global__` is meant to decribe a kernel, a kernel is a function parallelized among threads. By convention, it has no return values, and you must pass data from pointers on device memory.

Will the operation you want to achieve performed by one thread only ?
The solution i'll suggest is applicable if you want each thread of a kernel to be the sum of two vectors.

use the `__host__ __device__` keywords.

By doing so you function will be defined as callable within a CPU "usual" function, and inside a kernel (by the GPU).

You must now write a kernel (with `__global__` keyword to read each vector you want to add)

Comment: "By convention" sounds too weak. Kernel execution is generally asynchronous to the host, so a return value makes no sense without some kind of `future` type which in turn is something rather high-level.